# send a simple email from an angular controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, email

I have created a form using the angular.js and bootstrap which successfully validates on it's submission to the controller. My plan was to invoke phpmailer but despite following many interpretations of how to do this, I cannot get it to work. The email form only has 3 fields but to simplify the process further I just tried to call a test email with hardcoded content just to get the ball rolling. The php code is as follows:

```
            <?php

            require("class.phpmailer.php");

            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
            $mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com"; // SMTP server
            $mail->Username = “my-control-panel-username”;
            $mail->Password = my-control-panel-password;


            $mail->From     = "from@example.com";
            $mail->AddAddress("destination-email-address-to-go-here");

            $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
            $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
            $mail->WordWrap = 50;

            if(!$mail->Send()) {
              echo 'Message was not sent.';
              echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
              echo 'Message has been sent.';
            }
            ?>
```

Incidentally my controller code before giving up and simply calling the hard coded email was:

```
            app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

                // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred      
                $scope.submitForm = function() {
                    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
                    if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {

                        var data = {
                            "name" : $scope.userForm.fullName,
                            "email" : $scope.userForm.email,
                            "message" : $scope.userForm.message  
                        }


                        $http.post("testemail.php", data)
                        .success(function(data){
                            alert('sent');
                        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert('not sent');
                        });

                    }                               

                };

             });
```

What I could do with is verification on whether the php file looks ok and if so what code can I use to call it from the controller. OR.. is there a simpler way to send 3 form fields in an email. The email itself doesn't need to look pretty as long as the content is there. Many thanks.

Comment: Are you receiving emails from that script?

Comment: have you try different recipient for testing? Microsoft might just not let it pass. Gmail should, depending on your hosting settings and rep

Comment: But yes this is pretty much a simple way to dot it. Angular itself wont send email but posting it to php to do so is fairly simple. Just have to get the headers right.

Comment: Thanks for your help although I've checked everything but there's still smtp connection problems. I'm going to try something completely different.